# How to allow https to access content from wowza http link?

Tags: codeigniter, http, https, wowza, clappr

I have one question. Recently i have get link from my streaming server to play in my website. My streaming server use http link but my website use https ssl. During i get the link to play it cannot get content from my streaming server by show the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujn9o.png)

I am looking forward to hearing from all of you soon.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Chhenghong

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because you cannot access HTTP resource from HTTPS page, for security consideration. It is the browser behaviour.

To fix this issue, a proxy endpoint can be made in server side, such as `/proxy/playlist.m3u8`, which accept HTTP GET request. The browser will fetch the resource from `https://<your-server>/proxy/playlist.m3u8`, as if it is stored in your host. As it is an HTTPS request, no error.

In the server side, when `GET` request to `/proxy/playlist.m3u8` is listened, the HTTP request would be proxied to your streaming server (send `GET` request to the streaming server with all headers, parameters and body). When the response from streaming server is received, the response would be returned to browser directly, with all response headers and data.

As the HTTP request to streaming server happens in your server side, the restriction logic from browser does not apply any more.

For example, if the server is written in Node.js, with Express and `request` module, the proxy endpoint would look like:

```
app.get('/proxy/playlist.m3u8', function(req, res) {
  req.pipe(request('http://<streaming-server>/path/playlist.m3u8')).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Dear Shaochuancs, because my streaming server use http but my website use https the problem right now my streaming server block my request.

Comment: @chhenghong what do you mean by "block my request"?

Comment: @chhenghong Does the streaming server return response? Have your server received it? Can you post your proxy code?

Comment: everything working fine. The error message is that "This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Comment: @chhenghong I guess this error message is displayed on browser? Is your proxy endpoint served via HTTPS or HTTP?

Comment: this error when https make request to http. yes it error on browser

Comment: @chhenghong Is your proxy endpoint (e.g. `/proxy/playlist.m3u8`) served via HTTPS or HTTP? Please make it HTTPS

Comment: do you know another ways to solve it? without apply SSL?

Comment: @chhenghong Sorry but I don't think so. The restriction that HTTPS page cannot load HTTP resource is a browser security policy. Without apply SSL, I don't know any other workaround. Anyway, if your website is already serving HTTPS, it would be very easy to serve the proxy endpoint as HTTPS too.

Comment: Thanks you so much dear